# Is the parameter of time() modified if -1 is returned?

Tags: c++

**Update:**

Yes: the parameter and the return value of `time()` will both be `-1` on error. I added the GNU code in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267132).

**Original Question:**

The `time()` function is declared as: `std::time_t time(std::time_t* arg);`

Does `arg` get updated if `time()` returns `-1`?

```
time_t arg = 42;
time_t result = time(&arg);

cout << "arg: " << arg << ", result: " << result << endl;
```

Does this return `arg: 42, result: -1` or `arg: -1, result: -1`?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time states:

> Returns the current calendar time encoded as a `std::time_t` object, and also stores it in the object pointed to by `arg`, unless `arg` is a `null` pointer.
>
> **Return value:**
>
> Current calendar time encoded as `std::time_t` object on success, `(std::time_t)(-1)` on error. If arg is not `null`, the return value is also stored in the object pointed to by `arg`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/ states:

> Get the current calendar time as a value of type `time_t`.
>
> The function returns this value, and if the argument is not a `null` pointer, it also sets this value to the object pointed by `arg`.
>
> **Return value:**
>
> If the argument is not a null pointer, the return value is the same as the one stored in the location pointed by argument timer.
>
> If the function could not retrieve the calendar time, it returns a value of -1.

If `arg` is going to be set whether or not the function returns `-1`, should I skip initializing the variable?

```
time_t arg; // not initialized
time_t result = time(&arg);
```

Comment: The fact that you spent this much thought on it, indicates that the next programmer to read this will probably have the same questions so you might as well just initialize it. It costs basically nothing.

Comment: Use `std::chrono::one_of_the_clocks::now()` instead and subvert the whole issue?

Comment: My compiler complained that `time_t arg;` was begin used without first being initialized. I could have used `time_t arg = -1;` but that seems pointless if the value will be set on the very next line. Ultimately, I was just trying to determine whether `arg` would remain unchanged *iff* `time()` were to return `-1` (some functions leave the param unchanged if it returns an error value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C11 standard (which the C++ standard refers to for C library functions) says, in 7.27.2.4/3:

> The `time` function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the current
>   calendar time. The value `(time_t)(-1)` is returned if the calendar time is not
>   available. **If `timer` is not a null pointer, the return value is also assigned to the object it points to.**

So in your code the value of `arg` will always be written, and you don't need to initialize it.

Note that it would be better practice to just omit it entirely and write `time_t result = time(NULL);`.

Answer (score 0):

The param **will** return `-1` on error.

GNU [time.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/posix/time.c) is defined as follows:

```
/* Return the current time as a `time_t' and also put it in *T if T is
   not NULL.  Time is represented as seconds from Jan 1 00:00:00 1970.  */
time_t
time (time_t *t)
{
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t result;

  if (__gettimeofday (&tv, (struct timezone *) NULL))
    result = (time_t) -1;
  else
    result = (time_t) tv.tv_sec;

  if (t != NULL)
    *t = result;
  return result;
}
```